# 256bit AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding with Bouncy Castle

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle, aes

I am having trouble mapping the following JDK JCE encryption code to Bouncy Castles Light-weight API:

```
public String dec(String password, String salt, String encString) throws Throwable {
    // AES algorithm with CBC cipher and PKCS5 padding
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "BC");

    // Construct AES key from salt and 50 iterations 
    PBEKeySpec pbeEKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), toByte(salt), 50, 256);
    SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithSHA256And256BitAES-CBC-BC");
    SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyFactory.generateSecret(pbeEKeySpec).getEncoded(), "AES");

    // IV seed for first block taken from first 32 bytes
    byte[] ivData = toByte(encString.substring(0, 32));
    // AES encrypted data
    byte[] encData = toByte(encString.substring(32));

    cipher.init( Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec( ivData ) );

    return new String( cipher.doFinal( encData ) );
}
```

The above works great, but is not very portable due to Oracle's restriction on encryption strengths. I've made several attempts at porting to Bouncy Castles Light-weight API but without success.

```
public String decrypt1(String password, String salt, String encString) throws Exception {

    byte[] ivData = toByte(encString.substring(0, 32));
    byte[] encData = toByte(encString.substring(32));

    PKCS12ParametersGenerator gen = new PKCS12ParametersGenerator(new SHA256Digest());
    gen.init(password.getBytes(), toByte(salt), 50);
    CBCBlockCipher cbcBlockcipher = new CBCBlockCipher(new RijndaelEngine(256));
    CipherParameters params = gen.generateDerivedParameters(256, 256);

    cbcBlockcipher.init(false, params);

    PaddedBufferedBlockCipher aesCipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(cbcBlockcipher, new PKCS7Padding());
    byte[] plainTemp = new byte[aesCipher.getOutputSize(encData.length)];
    int offset = aesCipher.processBytes(encData, 0, encData.length, plainTemp, 0);
    int last = aesCipher.doFinal(plainTemp, offset);
    byte[] plain = new byte[offset + last];
    System.arraycopy(plainTemp, 0, plain, 0, plain.length);
    return new String(plain);
}
```

The above attempt results in a org.bouncycastle.crypto.DataLengthException: last block incomplete in decryption.

I have searched for examples online, but there isn't many examples of providing your own IV data for 256bit AES with CBC using PKCS5/PKCS7 as padding.

NB: The toByte function converts a String into a byte array using base64 or similar.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
public String dec(String password, String salt, String encString)
        throws Exception {

    byte[] ivData = toByte(encString.substring(0, 32));
    byte[] encData = toByte(encString.substring(32));

    // get raw key from password and salt
    PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(),
            toByte(salt), 50, 256);
    SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory
            .getInstance("PBEWithSHA256And256BitAES-CBC-BC");
    SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyFactory.generateSecret(
            pbeKeySpec).getEncoded(), "AES");
    byte[] key = secretKey.getEncoded();

    // setup cipher parameters with key and IV
    KeyParameter keyParam = new KeyParameter(key);
    CipherParameters params = new ParametersWithIV(keyParam, ivData);

    // setup AES cipher in CBC mode with PKCS7 padding
    BlockCipherPadding padding = new PKCS7Padding();
    BufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(
            new CBCBlockCipher(new AESEngine()), padding);
    cipher.reset();
    cipher.init(false, params);

    // create a temporary buffer to decode into (it'll include padding)
    byte[] buf = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(encData.length)];
    int len = cipher.processBytes(encData, 0, encData.length, buf, 0);
    len += cipher.doFinal(buf, len);

    // remove padding
    byte[] out = new byte[len];
    System.arraycopy(buf, 0, out, 0, len);

    // return string representation of decoded bytes
    return new String(out, "UTF-8");
}
```

I assume that you're actually doing hex encoding for `toByte()` since your code uses 32 characters for the IV (which provides the necessary 16 bytes). While I don't have the code you used to do the encryption, I did verify that this code will give the same decrypted output as your code.

Comment: are you sure it is correct to assume the IV to be the first 32 characters ? If so, what is this based on ?

Comment: `SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory
            .getInstance("PBEWithSHA256And256BitAES-CBC-BC");` and other lines aren't lightweight API, are they?