# Where is the Bouncy Castle API documentation?

Tags: c#, bouncycastle

I need to do some cryptography based work, and I have found out Bouncy Castle API which is both available for C# and Java, for Java it has documentation, but it has no documentation for C#.

Can anyone provide me some resources from where I can get idea for using Bouncy Castle with C#?

Comment: Someone asked the same question on GitHub: https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/issues/443

Answer (score 18):

I also couldn't find any C#-documentation for Bouncy Castle API. Seems, like it doesn't exist.

But you can go this way. Download library sources, and look at them a little. Code actually looks like Java-code, but it has minimal differences:

1. Some base classes moved to interfaces
2. All the methods and properties are named in 'UpperCamelCase'

Therefore you can freely use Java-documentation. And finally, some [example for it usage in C#](https://web.archive.org/web/20140324180459/http://elian.co.uk/post/2009/07/29/Bouncy-Castle-CSharp.aspx).

Also, want to add, [answer for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641326/256bit-aes-cbc-pkcs5padding-with-bouncy-castle#5641932) really helps me in one time.

Answer (score 1):

I found some getting started document for the FIPS compliant C# version on the [bouncyCastle website](https://downloads.bouncycastle.org/fips-csharp/BC-FNA-UserGuide-1.0.1.pdf) which helped a bit, but seems to not to be up to date - according to Joe Huang.

However, I did some [toy application](https://github.com/lockejan/secure-text-editor/tree/main/BcFactory) during a university assignment.
Might help others seeking for some examples.

I can also recommend looking into the tests of the bouncyCastle source code to get a better understanding of the API.

Comment: That's out of date.